# defining object method outside its class block, any reason not to?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

The following surprised me, although perhaps it shouldn't have. However, I've never seen this done elsewhere

```
def bar_method(self):
    print( f"in Foo method bar, baz={self.baz}")
    # and pages more code in the real world


class Foo(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.baz = "Quux"
   bar = bar_method

>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.bar()
in Foo method bar, baz=Quux
>>>
```

This follows from the definition of `def` which is an assignment of a function object to its name in the current context.

The great advantage, as far as I am concerned, is that I can move large method definitions outside the class body and even into a different file, and merely link them into the class with a single assignment. Instantiating the class binds them as usual.

My question is simply, why have I never seen this done before? Is there anything lurking here that might bite me? Or if it's regarded as bad style, why?

(If you are wondering about my context, it's about Django View and Form subclasses. I would dearly love to keep them short, so that the business logic behind them is easy to follow. I'd far rather that methods of only cosmetic significance were moved elsewhere).

Comment: It is less readable, since if you go to the `foo` class, then it does not show that method. Furthermore the `__name__` here is `bar_method`, not `bar` and it is not clear what the `self` will be here. An IDE for example can not help (much) with autocomplete of `self`.

Comment: You ask "why not", I ask "why" ? What you posted has "great advantage" is actually a huge disadvantage. Imagine debugging or even trying to understand a class implementation spread across 5 different files

Answer (score 1):

> The great advantage, as far as I am concerned, is that I can move large method definitions outside the class body and even into a different file

I personnally wouldn't consider this as "a great advantage".

> My question is simply, why have I never seen this done before?

Because there are very few good reasons to do so, and a lot of good reasons to NOT do so.

> Or if it's regarded as bad style, why?

Because it makes it much harder to understand what's going on, quite simply. Debugging is difficult enough, and each file you have to navigate too adds to the "mental charge".

> I would dearly love to keep them short, so that the business logic behind them is easy to follow. I'd far rather that methods of only cosmetic significance were moved elsewhere

Then put the important parts at the beginning of the class statement and the cosmetic ones at the end.

Also, ask yourself whether you're doing things at the right place - as far as I'm concerned, "business logic" mainly belongs to the domain layer (models), and "cosmetic" rather suggests presentation layer (views / templates). Of course some objects (forms and views specially) are actually dealing with both business rules and presentation, but even then you can often move some of this domain part to models (which the view or form will call on) and some of this presentation part to the template layer (using filters / custom tags).

My 2 cents...

NB: sorry if the above sounds a bit patronizing - I don't know what your code looks like, so I can't tell whether you're obviously already aware of this and doing the right thing already and just trying to improve further, or you're a beginner still fighting with how to achieve proper code separation...

Comment: I don't take offense. But the problem can't be avoided by moving methods to the end of the class, because it's the flow from one View to another that it's important to follow, and the cosmetic methods just get in the way by being inbetween View1 and View2.

Comment: BTW I find scrolling up and down through hundreds of lines of code far more irksome than clicking to another tab or window with another file open therein. Maybe just me.

Comment: @nigel222: I think you should look if you can refactor long methods. Usually methods should not be longer than 40-50 lines, and 20 or more is already "suspicious". Try looking for common patterns, and abstract these away in helper functions.

Comment: @nigel222 using class-based views ? I have to say that I don't unless I _really_ need them (which is almost never) - they only make simple things uselessly complicated as far as I'm concerned. But anyway: if your question is "how to best move 'noise' code out of my view", it's difficult to answer without seeing the code.

Comment: Oh and yes: lots of code editors have features like folding, object inspectors etc, which makes navigation easier. Not that I use those features much either since my editor allows me to split a same file in two or more side-by-side views so I can easily see two different points at once (and navigate indepently in each view).